# Движение изображения вместе с прогрессбаром

Tags: c#, wpf

Народ, кто может подсказать как такое реализовать?
Пытаюсь сделать красивый прогрессбар с эффектом свечения, которое как отдельную картинку хочу заставить следовать за заполнением прогрессбара

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-нибудь пробовали делать уже?

Comment: пробовал разные стили, но все не то, или я разобраться не смог, в интернете то что нужно, не нашел,

Comment: добавляйте примеры кода, что именно пробовали

Comment: и хотя бы картинку - как вы себе представляете результат

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i701/1512/60/7323df5f45ec.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать добавить зависимость левого отступа у картинки от текущего значения прогресс бара. Т.е. каждый раз, когда меняется значение бара, меняется и отступ у картинки в соответствии с этим значением.